# Master Detail data bindings with ComboBox details [WinForms]

Tags: winforms, data-binding

Trying to set up a master detail scenario where the details will have a combo box. Is there a way to make each detail item retain its selection using pure data binding or is there some manual plumbing that needs to be done here.

Recreation steps for the sample below:

1. Change M1's details to "Detail2"
2. Switch to master M2 and then back to M1
3. Details reverts back to Detail1. I'm expecting it to retain the previously selected value

Form constructor:

```
InitializeComponent ();

List<MasterData> dataList = new List<MasterData> ();

dataList.Add (new MasterData ("M1"));
dataList.Add (new MasterData ("M2"));

// master data
this.masterBindingSource.DataSource = typeof (MasterData);
this.masterBindingSource.DataSource = dataList;

this.masterComboBox.DataSource = this.masterBindingSource;
this.masterComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

// details                    
this.detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "Details";
this.detailsBindingSource.DataSource = this.masterBindingSource;

this.detailsComboBox.DataBindings.Add (new System.Windows.Forms.Binding ("SelectedValue", this.masterBindingSource,
    "SelectedDetail", true));

this.detailsComboBox.DataSource = this.detailsBindingSource;
this.detailsComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

// Label to make sure the master is actually changing
this.detailLabel.DataBindings.Add (new System.Windows.Forms.Binding ("Text", this.masterBindingSource, 
    "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Data:

```
public class Details
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Details (string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class MasterData
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
    public Details SelectedDetail { get; set; }

    public MasterData (string name)
    {
        this.Details = new List<Details> ();
        this.Name = name;

        this.Details.Add (new Details ("Detail1"));
        this.Details.Add (new Details ("Detail2"));
        this.SelectedDetail = this.Details.FirstOrDefault ();
    }
}
```

I'm coming from a WPF background and struggling to understand binding in WinForms hopefully this all made sense.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing. Could you maybe explain it from a controls point of view.

Comment: @jcwrequests that's the problem with winforms, that you can't really design the UI without referring to "controls", in WPF the UI is realized by an abstraction of it (the ViewModel) and DataBinding. winforms' databinding is a ridiculous joke and does not allow any of that.

Comment: @kbeal2k why are you going backwards? winforms is a really old technology no one cares about. If you already know WPF, why don't you use that?

Comment: Winforms has its place on its possible to do binding it's just not as robust as WPF. I use WinForms all the time and am able to MVVM but I use the RX framework along with binding.

Comment: Here is a link to what I mean.  http://hotgazpacho.org/2012/07/reactive-extensions-with-winforms/

Comment: @jcwrequests I don't care dude, winforms is useless. It doesn't support customization of anything, and it is horribly slower on large collections, because it lacks UI virtualization. Why would anyone care about such a dead technology?

Comment: If you use tools loke those made by Infragistics you can style a WinForm application. It is a about the best tool for the job. Like I said WinForms has its place and so does WPF and so does Javascript apps. IMHO its easier to quickly put together a WinForm App then WPF.

Comment: @jcwrequests yeah, surely, except Infragistics is a paid product that costs lots of $$$ and you get better stuff from WPF for free. Not to mention no matter how hard Infragistics will try, they will never make winforms be hardware-accelerated, vector-based, or resolution independent.

Comment: I am just saying that you should never assume that one way is better than another until you have all the facts. Believe me I understand what you are saying. But to dismiss something because its old is also a mistake.

Comment: @jcwrequests sure, I'm planning to do some GW Basic stuff in my spare time, too. Please, dude...

Comment: We are welcome to our opinions. Its has been fun debating with you but this is not a religious debate. And to quote an Old Film Monty Python The Search For The Holy Grail "I fart in your general direction." Seriously have a good weekend its been run.

Comment: I'm on a project with a large Winforms legacy code base. If this was a Greenfield project with no external dependencies I'd use WPF no question. Unfortunately the real world doesn't always allow that.

Comment: @kbeal2k then either use the existing winforms stuff with winforms techniques (horrible code behind for everything). winforms' databinding is ridiculous and useless, don't try to use it as if it were WPF.

Comment: (attempting to unhijack this thread) Here is the pattern I'm trying to follow. http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2009/08/mvp-mvvm-winforms-data-binding.html